# why element Id as a computed property in ember view not working in ember 1.0.0-PRE.4?

Tags: ember.js

Below is the jsfiddle describing the issue. First view has elementid as a computed property and second one has a explicit element id. First view's id has not got changed while the second one has the id.
http://jsfiddle.net/LZjEx/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MultiView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : 'appl',
     textInput: Ember.TextField.extend({
        elementId : function(){
            return "disk";
        }.property()
    })
})

App.MultiView.create().append();

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appl">
    {{view view.textInput}}
    {{view Ember.TextField elementId="answer"}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging and experiments, here is what I found:

In this thread it is explained when the elementId is set: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1549

> Since the view registers itself with Ember.View.views on init it needs the elementId defined before init is run. It doesn't have to do with 'inDOM' state.

Here is a fiddle confirming that: http://jsfiddle.net/LLSQD/

```
App.MultiView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : 'appl',

     textInput: Ember.TextField.extend({
        init: function() {
            // This view's id will not be set to 'disk'.
            return this._super();
            this.set('elementId', 'disk');
        }
    }),
    textInput2: Ember.TextField.extend({
        init: function() {
            // This view's id will be set to 'answer'.
            this.set('elementId', 'answer');
            return this._super();
        }
    })
})
```

In this thread it is explained, that computed properties are not computed before initialization: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/777

> This has been discussed before. create extends prototypes, it's not for setting computed property values. This isn't something that is going to change. You can consider using setProperties if you want this.

Overall, because the elementId is used at prototype initialisation, it cannot be changed after the object is constructed, thus using a computed property to determine the id is wrong. The best you can do is set the id in the init method and then call this._super();

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Works well